# use multiple methods to print a sales report

Tags: java

I keep on getting a error when I tried to run the program. I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Main.displayBody(Main.java:27)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

What should I do to fix it? The following is the program that I have started. What I need to do is set the Main controller with methods and write a program that contains the methods main(), displayHeader(), displayBody(), and displayFooter(). Then main() calls displayHeader(), displayBody(), and displayFooter() and displayHeader() prints the heading area. Lastly, displayBody() reads the file Lab6Data.txt, prints the body, accumulates a total until 'quit' is read, and returns the total.

Expected output:

Sales Report
Name..........Amount

Abbot.......2,685
Coswell.....1,745
Freedwick...6,283
Gibson......5,453

Total......16,166

This is the file to be read:

Abbot

2685

Coswell

1745

Freedwick

6283

Gibson

5453

quit

0

This is the code I have started:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayHeader();
    displayBody();       
    displayFooter();
  }
public static void displayHeader() {
    String header = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sales Report");
    System.out.println("Name......Amount"); 
  }
  public static void displayBody() {
    String throwaway = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
       String name = sc.nextLine();
       throwaway = sc.nextLine();
       if (name.equals("quit")) break;
       int amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
       throwaway = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.println("name......"+name+" amount"+amount);
    }
  }
  public static void displayFooter() {

    String totalSum = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
      int sum =0;
      int total = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
      sum += total;
       System.out.println("Total....." + sum);
    }         
  }
  }
```

Comment: * java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""* the message is quiet clear. You try to parse an empty String as an int

Comment: "_Lastly, displayBody() reads the file Lab6Data.txt_" - but you don't read that file (at least not with your `Scanner`), your `Scanner` points to `System.in`.

Comment: "displayBody() reads the file Lab6Data.txt" - no it doesn't. It reads from `System.in` which is normally the command line terminal.

Comment: You might want to step through your code with a debugger but I _guess_ your problem is here (or one of them): `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())` - if the scanner reads an empty line or anything that isn't just an integer parsing will fail. Either use `nextInt()` if you _know_ you should get an `int`, check the line content before trying to parse or put a try-catch block around that code.

Comment: you also have multiple scanners listening in on System.in which is never good. it's better to use one scanner in the main and pass the String to the functions instead

Answer (score 0):

1 you are using multiple scanners that listening in on a single source (System.in) which is a very bad practice.

2 each time you call `sc.nextLine()` you are consuming a line of input. so all your throwAways are actually eating up legitimate inputs

3"displayBody() reads the file Lab6Data.txt" no it doesn't. right now it's receiving data from the System.in. if you want to read from a file you need to replace

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
```

with

```
File file = new File("your file path in here");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Finally this is what your code should look like

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //replace scanner here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        displayHeader();
        displayBody(sc);
    }
    public static void displayHeader() {
        System.out.println("Sales Report");
        System.out.println("Name......Amount");
        System.out.println("Enter 'quit' to quit");
    }
    public static void displayBody(Scanner sc) {
        int sum =0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            if (name.equals("quit")){
                System.out.println("Total....." + sum);
                break;
            }
            int amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            sum += amount;
            System.out.println("name......"+name+" amount "+amount);
        }
    }
```